# unable to keep the table updated using java script

Tags: javascript, html

once we enter the data and submit the data is lost..plz help solve this issue
i need to display the updated table everytime proper data is submited. when ever i try to submit the data in the form it updates the tables and the page is like a new refreshed page.

`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function updatetable()
        {
            alert("hello");
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
            var age = document.getElementById("age");
            var email = document.getElementById("email");

            if(fname.value == "" || lname.value == "" || age.value == "" || email.value ==  "")
            {
                alert("Please enter data in all the fields");
                return;
            } 
            if(age.value < 1 || age.value > 100)
            {
                alert("enter age properly");
                return;
            }


            var tab = document.getElementById("table1");
            var row = tab.insertRow(-1);

            var cell=[];
            for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                cell[i] = row.insertCell(i);
                cell.innerHTML=document.forms["dataform"].elements[i].value;
            }

        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="dataform">
        First name:
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="first_name">
        Last name:
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name">
        Age:
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" min="1" max="100">
        Email:
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
        <input type="submit" name="submitdata" value="Submit" onclick="updatetable()"/>

    </form> 


        <br><br>

        <table id="table1" cellpadding="30">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Have you tried preventDefault?

Comment: @Zim84: he need to pass event object as function argument to use preventDefault() on that object, easy solution is just to convert submit button to normal button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a normal button instead of submit, this may solve your problem.

```js
function updatetable()
        {
            alert("hello");
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
            var age = document.getElementById("age");
            var email = document.getElementById("email");

            if(fname.value == "" || lname.value == "" || age.value == "" || email.value ==  "")
            {
                alert("Please enter data in all the fields");
                return;
            } 
            if(age.value < 1 || age.value > 100)
            {
                alert("enter age properly");
                return;
            }


            var tab = document.getElementById("table1");
            var row = tab.insertRow(-1);

            var cell=[]
            for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                cell[i] = row.insertCell(i);
                          cell[i].innerHTML=document.forms["dataform"].elements[i].value;
            }

        }
```

```html
<body>
   <div>
    <form name="dataform">
        First name:
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="first_name">
        Last name:
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name">
        Age:
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" min="1" max="100">
        Email:
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
        <input type="button" name="submitdata" value="Submit" onclick="updatetable()"/>

    </form> 
    </div>

        <br><br>

        <table id="table1" cellpadding="30">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </table>
</body>
```

Comment: @Shashank Karukonda , You can try this.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code deeply and found you have 2 mistakes

first in html

replace

```
 <input type="submit" name="submitdata" value="Submit" onclick="updatetable()"/>
```

With

```
 <input type="button" name="submitdata" value="Submit" onclick="updatetable()"/>
```

second in javascript inside a for loop

replace

```
 cell.innerHTML=document.forms["dataform"].elements[i].value;
```

with

```
 cell[i].innerHTML=document.forms["dataform"].elements[i].value;
```

here is the working demo of your code
https://jsfiddle.net/cxz3Lwou/14/

hope it helps
:)

Comment: doing that doesnt update the table...it shows no change

Comment: try removing the `value="Submit"`.

Comment: @Bibek: removing value will remove the text displaying on button and is not related solution for issue described. so -1 to your comment from my end

Comment: Sorry, I though you converted it to `<button>` tag. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

A submit button (`<input type="submit">`) inside the form will submit the form when clicked on, refreshing the page. If you do not want to the form to submit, change the button to `<input type="button">` which will not submit the form. You should also use a query selector to get all the inputs inside the form.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function updatetable()
        {
            alert("hello");
            var fname = document.getElementById("fname");
            var lname = document.getElementById("lname");
            var age = document.getElementById("age");
            var email = document.getElementById("email");

            if(fname.value == "" || lname.value == "" || age.value == "" || email.value ==  "")
            {
                alert("Please enter data in all the fields");
                return;
            } 
            if(age.value < 1 || age.value > 100)
            {
                alert("enter age properly");
                return;
            }


            var tab = document.getElementById("table1");
            var row = tab.insertRow(-1);
            var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('form[name=dataform] input');
            //var cell = row.cells;
            for(var i=0;i<4;i++)
            {
                var cell = row.insertCell(i);
               cell.innerHTML = inputs[i].value;
            }

        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <form name="dataform">
        First name:
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="first_name">
        Last name:
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="last_name">
        Age:
        <input type="number" id="age" name="age" min="1" max="100">
        Email:
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
        <input type="button" name="submitdata" value="Submit" onclick="updatetable()"/>

    </form> 


        <br><br>

        <table id="table1" cellpadding="30">
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you explain the difference of using query selector instead of what i have used?